# Replacing a part of a string with an initialized variable using the string replace function?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, replace

I want to know how to use the replace function of a string to replace a part of a string with an initialized variable. I know you can use the replace function like `string.replace(0,5,"*****)` but that's not what I want to do. Let's say I have `string randString = "apple";`. How would I go about using the replace function to replace a string with the letter "e" from the word apple instead of using `string.replace(0,1,"e");` I want it to be something like this `string.replace(0,1,randString[4]);`

EDIT: I have a random string made of 0's and 1's and I want to replace a part of the string with this `randomStr.replace(0,1,bin[0][6]);` Where `bin[0]` is just one of many binary numbers that I have. `bin[0][6]` is the position of the last number at the end of the binary. For example bin[0] = 1001011 and bin[0][6] is 1.

Comment: That should work fine.  What is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Hi, I edited my code and rephrased my question a little bit.Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string randString = "xxxx";
    string target = "hello";

    target.replace(0, 2, randString);
    cout<<target<<endl;

    return 0;
}


--output:--
xxxxllo
```

2)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string randString = "0000";
    string replacement = "0001";

    randString.replace(0, 1, replacement.substr(3, 1));
    cout<<randString<<endl;


    return 0;
}


--output:--
1000
```

Comment: Hi, I rephrased my question a little bit. Please take a look.

Comment: @user2419691, added another solution.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the parameters of (3,1) mean? Is it (position, value)?

Comment: Lookup the string::substr() function.  It's good practice to know how to look up things in the docs.

Comment: @user2419691, The reason subscripting didn't work is because the subscript operator returns a char type--not a string type, and string::replace() requires a string type.